# How to change iOS in app purchase when changing to lifetime membership instead of subscription?

Tags: xcode, in-app-purchase

Our app allows users to either have a 1 month subscription, or a lifetime subscription. 1 Month is an auto-renew subscription, where lifetime is obviously a one time purchase.

Our issue arises when a user has a 1 month subscription, and wants to change to a lifetime subscription, we aren't sure how to cancel the user's monthly subscription for them, or if that is even possible.